# NetBeans Console doesn't show strings

Tags: javascript, logging, netbeans, console, output

I am using that function to log some data

```
console.log("DoWin(), inputHistory=%s", inputHistory)
```

In chrome console it show the result correctly but in Netbeans Console it show it like that

```
DoWin(), inputHistory=%s
```

I tried all other stuff like %o, %d all same doesn't replace with the value but in chrome console it works fine

How can I change that?

Comment: Always use Chrome? Change console.log on the ones that aren't Chrome?

Comment: What do you mean? I am using plugin for chrome with netbeans